# Encrypting and Decrypting query string causes unknown text to be appended

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, encryption

Net app with .Net framework 4.0.
To encrypt and decrypt the query string i use the below code block.
the funny thing is when i try to decrypt a string for instance

```
string a = "username=testuser&email=testmail@yahoo.com"
```

after decrypt

```
string b = "username=testuser&email=testmail@yahoo.com\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0"
```

Im not sure why the "\0" is appended to my decrypted value.

How can i prevent this ?

code block i use for encypt and decrypt is -

```
public string EncryptQueryString(string inputText, string key, string salt)
        {
            byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputText);

            using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                PasswordDeriveBytes secretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt));
                using (ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16)))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                            cryptoStream.FlushFinalBlock();
                            string base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());

                            // Generate a string that won't get screwed up when passed as a query string.
                            string urlEncoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(base64);
                            return urlEncoded;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public string DecryptQueryString(string inputText, string key, string salt)
        {
            byte[] encryptedData = Convert.FromBase64String(inputText);
            PasswordDeriveBytes secretKey = new PasswordDeriveBytes(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key), Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt));

            using (RijndaelManaged rijndaelCipher = new RijndaelManaged())
            {
                using (ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndaelCipher.CreateDecryptor(secretKey.GetBytes(32), secretKey.GetBytes(16)))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(encryptedData))
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                        {
                            byte[] plainText = new byte[encryptedData.Length];
                            cryptoStream.Read(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
                            string utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
                            return utf8;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: As a side note: When you're using multiple `using` statements, you can (and should) omit the opening and closing block braces, let alone the innermost pair. By doing that, you avoid unnecessary indentation and improve the readability.

Comment: You are using `cryptoStream.Read` incorrectly. It needs to be called repeatedly until everything has been decrypted, and you must inspect the return value to see how much has been decrypted.

Comment: @MariusSchulz: I'd say that's a personal preference.  The indented version seems more readable to me..

Comment: @ChrisLively It always is ;-). Still, I definitely prefer this formatting style: https://gist.github.com/mariusschulz/6594870

Comment: throw out those useless streams and use `encryptor.TransformFinalBlock` and `decryptor.TransformFinalBlock`

Answer (score 2):

Change the following lines:

```
cryptoStream.Read(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
string utf8 = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
return utf8;
```

to

```
StringBuilder outputValue = new StringBuilder();

byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int readCount = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
while (readCount > 0) {
    outputValue.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, readCount));
    readCount = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}

return outputValue.ToString();
```

Another version of the above:

```
String outputValue = String.Empty;
using ( MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream() ) {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int readCount = 0;
    while ((readCount = cryptoStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
        outputStream.Write(buffer, 0, readCount);
    }

    return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(outputStream.ToArray());

}
```

Essentially the Read is appending null characters to pad out the string.  By limiting it down to the actual number of decrypted characters you'll get the only original string back.

The above takes into consideration that the cryptoStream.Read may not read the entire string in one go.  I haven't tested this yet (will be later today), but it looks good.

Comment: Read(,,x) reads *up to* x bytes, not exactly x bytes. So your current code might not decrypt all of the input. Better use a StreamReader and call ReadToEnd.

Comment: @dtb: I have this exact code in a production system.  Do you have more information I should take a look at if I'm not doing it right?  - thanks

Comment: "Implementations of this method read a **maximum** of count bytes from the current stream and store them in buffer beginning at offset." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx

Comment: @dtb: I may be dense, but I'm not seeing the issue.  If the max number is set to the length of the actual encrypted data length then how could this be less than the decrypted bytes?  A decrypted string won't contain *more* data than the encrypted version..

Comment: If you call Read(buffer, 0, x), then Read is allowed to read less than x bytes into buffer. For example, if you request 100 bytes, it is allowed to place 1 byte in the buffer. You need to call it again until the sum of return values has reached 100. If you want to read all bytes until the end of the stream, you need to call Read until it returns 0.

Comment: Guys thanks for the prompt response, if the issue is with padding, what if i turn the padding off, is that a feasible approach ?

Comment: No, the padding is working as intended. The problem is with how call the Read method. Don't try to cover the bug by messing with the padding. Fix the bug!

Comment: Jon Skeet explains it better than I do: http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/readbinary.html

Comment: Next problem: Stream.Read reads the data in arbitrary chunks, but Encoding.UTF8.GetString needs all bytes encoding one character together. If Read returns the first half of a character and in a second call the second half, the current code breaks. So either read all bytes into a byte[] first and then decode the whole array, or better wrap the Stream in a StreamReader and call the ReadToEnd method.

Comment: @dtb is the above problem still valid  with the updated code by Chris Lively ?

Comment: @JustinRusso: The last code block looks fine except it uses UTF-16LE instead of UTF-8 and wastes more resources than necessary. The code block in the middle is broken.

Comment: @dtb one quick question , the letter appended '\0\0' only happens to the email attribute. i have around 5 attributes i send but this happens to only email attribute. is this preferential - newbie to this !

Comment: @JustinRusso: AES/Rijndael works in blocks of 16 bytes. So if the input length is not a multiple of 16, it automatically appends as many bytes as needed to make the length a multiple of 16 (the padding). The padding is removed automatically removed when you decrypt the ciphertext (except if you're doing it wrong). Note, btw, that your methods provide confidentiality but no integrity. So while you can be sure that an attacker cannot read the encrypted information (as long as the key remains secret), the decrypting party cannot be sure that the result equals what the encrypting party encrypted.

Comment: Ohh i get it, so would it be fine for me to remove and trim the '\0' after decrypting. i know it might solve the issue only when i know it only appends to the email attribute ?